# Symfony: adding a block-prefix for an abstract custom type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a custom type that is `abstract`.
As it seems that leads to it not getting its own `block_prefix` in the hierarchy.
So I thought I would put that into `configureOptions`.
But in the deriving classes I do occassionally also have to define `configureOptions` which then again leads to either overwriting the parent method which defeats the purpose. Or if I call it explicitly
with `parent::configureOptions` the system will put the custom prefix above (in the sense of "higher priority") the automatically generated prefix of the implementing class which I obviously do not want.

Is there a solution to this problem that is not "make the parent class not abstract"?
I say that because if possible I don't want to loose the enforcement of the contract given by the abstract parent-class.

EDIT: I realized that it was a false assumption I made that making the base class non-abstract would lead to the addition of the class name as block-prefix.

Comment: How are you extending your abstract class? Are you aware that Symfony form inheritance uses a different (non-standard) mechanism for inheritance rather than standard `FooType extends BaseType`? It is done through the `getParent` method. Sadly, a brief search for docs on the matter came up empty.

Comment: Ohhh! That might turn out to be very useful! I will dig into this. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Runs into problems as the defined parent-class needs to be instantiated via the `getParent`-pseudo-inheritance. Hence not working as well. I have been thinking about ensuring contract-conformity by throwing "NotImplementedException" or something like that in the abstract base class "abstract" methods and in the end not make it abstract after all. Still seems hacky to me...